# PlayFramework Netty IllegalArgumentException: empty text

Tags: exception, playframework-2.0, netty

Every now and then play server throws this exception. Is there a way to stop or suppress it? does not seem to be causing any harm though.

```
[[31merror[0m] - play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: empty text
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:89) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:554) ~[netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.closeRequested(SimpleChannelHandler.java:334) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleDownstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:260) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.handleDownstream(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:106) [netty-http-pipelining-1.1.4.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:206) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:66) [play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelHandler.java:156) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:130) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:153) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
```

Comment: Which version of Play? It looks like the request is not specifying HTTP protocol version. According to [RFC 7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.1.1), the version is a required field. So maybe Netty is just being tolerant about the missing version and handling the request using some fallback (1.1?).

Comment: addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.3"). Is there a possible fix?

Comment: Not sure if there is a fix on the Netty side. But I think the real solution is to have clients behaving correctly. See [this discussion](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4077#issuecomment-82005918). Is this an internet facing application? You can also try to use the latest version of Play 2.4.x (which is 2.4.11 is fully compatible with the version you are using). But I doubt this will fix the problem.

Comment: So, apparently, there is a fix in Netty 4.0, but you then need to upgrade to Play 2.5.x. And the fix involves to returns a `400 Bad Request`.

Answer (score 0):

The client is the issue. The client does not send proper HTTP requests. This happens, for instance, if the akka cluster is configured to use the play port - it needs to use a separate port.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).